# Kafka Streams Serdes having nested generic doesn't work

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have following code which uses functional style to define two functions for kafka topics

```
    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, CloudEvent<ClassA>>, KStream<String, CloudEvent<ClassB>>> method1() {
         ....... //lambda
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, CloudEvent<ClassB>>, KStream<String, CloudEvent<ClassC>>> method2() {
        ...... //lambda
    }
```

For these two functions I define serdes so

```
    @Bean
    public Serde<CloudEventMessage<ClassA>> classASerde(ObjectMapper mapper, Validator validator) {     
        return StreamsSerdes.classASerde(mapper,validator);
    }

    @Bean
    public Serde<CloudEventMessage<ClassB>> classBSerde(ObjectMapper mapper, Validator validator) {     
        return StreamsSerdes.classBSerde(mapper,validator);
    }
```

This construction doesn't work as at runtime spring tries to deserialize `CloudEvent<ClassB>` with Serde of `CloutEvent<ClassA>`. **Is there someway to give hint to use the correct serde for method1 and method2 ?**

Secondly I could bypass the above issues by mentioning Serdes in application.properties

```
spring.application.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.method1-in-0.consumer.valueSerde=package.serde.StreamsSerdes$ClassASerde
spring.application.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.method2-in-0.consumer.valueSerde=package.serde.StreamsSerdes$ClassBSerde
```

However now I get other issues as these Serde classes don't have default constructor. I do need ObjectMapper, Validator from Spring to inject beans (@Service) to perfrom converstions/validations during deserialization.

Has anyone come across similar issues or perhaps have ideas how to resolve them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a gap that the nested generics are not working right now in the binder. Do you mind creating an issue in the repository and linking this thread?

As to the second issue that you are running into when providing properties in `application.properties`, you can try using a workaround. The `Serde` interface has a `configure` method that takes a map.

```
default void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        // intentionally left blank
    }
```

Override this method in your `Serde` implementation and set those bean objects under some keys.

```
ObjectMapper mapper;
Validator validator;


@Override
public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    this.mapper = (ObjectMapper) configs.get("mapper.key");
    this.validator = (Validator) configs.get("validator.key");
}
```

You need to remove accessing them from the constructor and use those fields directly for deserialization and serialization.

Then you provide this bean in your application to populate the map:

```
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer(ObjectMapper mapper, Validator validator) {

    return factoryBean -> {
        factoryBean.getStreamsConfiguration().put("mappeer.key", mapper);
        factoryBean.getStreamsConfiguration().put("validator.key", validator);
    };
}
```

I haven't tried this code in an application, but it is something that you can try and see if it works with your code.

Comment: Hi Sobychacko,
Thanks but I was not able to get your suggestion working. Serdes config method doesn't contain custom properties set via  StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer  (it however does contain defaults and other overridden properties from application.properties)

Comment: I have worked around it, by making nested object as String (thereby using default serde from binder) and  added mapValues to perform conversion and validation.
```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> method1() {
        return event -> event.mapValues(payload -> Serdes.deserializeClassA(payload, mapper, validator))
    .filterNot((key, value) -> Objects.isNull(value)) // catch validation exceptions else stream thread dies
    .....
    }
```